# Running 2 inserts, without thread pause and within transaction, does not work

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, transactions, .net-6.0

To identify the behavior of this issue, took me some time but now I have it.

Postgre SQL, .net6, Entity Framework direct query

The behavior of this code is such that unless I insert a `Sleep` between calls, not less than `15-20` seconds, this code will timeout at `sql2`.
Note, the call does not fail, if I set a huge timeout, it will execute forever. Both, `sql1` and `sql2` are `INSERT..SELECT`

```cs
using (var ctx = _dbContextFactoryCallback())
{
    recs1 = ExecSql(ctx, sql1, null);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
    recs2 = ExecSql(ctx, sql2, 60);
}


private int ExecSql(DbContext ctx, FormattableString sql, int? timeout)
{
    if (timeout.HasValue)
        ctx.Database.SetCommandTimeout(timeout.Value);
    return ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(sql);
}
```

But this code below will execute fine

```cs
using (var ctx = _dbContextFactoryCallback())
{
    recs1 = ExecSql(ctx, sql1, null);
    recs1 = ExecSql(ctx, sql1, null);
    recs1 = ExecSql(ctx, sql1, null);
}
```

I am not blaming EF/.net. Something obviously on DB side. Here is equivalent SQL transaction that also executes forever. And I mean - forever. Run each DML separately - works!

```sql
begin;
INSERT INTO table1
    (fields...)  
SELECT <some fields and couple hard-coded values>
FROM table1
WHERE 
  <few conditions>
GROUP BY 
  <same fields as SELECT>;

INSERT INTO table2 (f1, f2) -- INSERT SUBSET based on uncommitted data from ^^^
select c.id, a.id
FROM 
   table1 t1 Inner JOIN -- SELF JOIN
   table1 t2 a On <condition>
where 
    <where conditions>;

COMMIT;
```

My original wish was to execute it as atomic transaction

```cs
using (var ctx = _dbContextFactoryCallback())
{
    using (var tran = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        recs1 = ExecSql(ctx, sql1, null);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
        recs2 = ExecSql(ctx, sql2, 60);

        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

But with transaction even when using `Sleep` it does not work. Bottom line - separate calls/transactions works with a 20 second pause. **NOTE** - 3 straight `sql1` executed within transaction - works!

**-- Explain plan** (from 2nd query in transaction, after first query executed)

```
Insert on table2  (cost=220982.08..222767.83 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=1497.900..1497.902 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=220982.08..222767.83 rows=28181 width=40) (actual time=770.711..986.875 rows=94731 loops=1)
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=220982.08..222415.56 rows=28181 width=70) (actual time=770.635..934.304 rows=94731 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: (((a.someid)::text = (c.someid)::text) AND ((a.type)::text = (c.type)::text))
              ->  Sort  (cost=127241.69..127555.13 rows=125375 width=46) (actual time=673.203..737.628 rows=94731 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: a.someid, a.type
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 5208kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on table1 a  (cost=0.00..112768.01 rows=125375 width=46) (actual time=0.006..258.759 rows=94731 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((MustDoSome IS TRUE) AND (batchnumber = '2b86d81c-d76a-4184-b04f-6bdbeb78b51b'::uuid) AND (keytype = 1) AND (datarecordtype = 2))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 588905
              ->  Sort  (cost=93740.39..93787.02 rows=18650 width=46) (actual time=97.419..112.265 rows=94731 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: c.someid, c.type
                    Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 3448kB
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on statementdata c  (cost=727.30..92417.46 rows=18650 width=46) (actual time=8.072..44.686 rows=58677 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (stmtkeytype = 2)
                          Filter: ((batchnumber = '2b86d81c-d76a-4184-b04f-6bdbeb78b51b'::uuid) AND (datarecordtype = 2))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 58677
                          Heap Blocks: exact=16204
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fki_fk_table1_stmt_key_type  (cost=0.00..722.63 rows=58428 width=0) (actual time=5.263..5.263 rows=117354 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (stmtkeytype = 2)
Planning Time: 0.557 ms
Trigger for constraint fk_xxx_zz_yyy_id: time=899.588 calls=94731
Trigger for constraint fk_xxx_yyy_id: time=837.080 calls=94731
Trigger for constraint fk_RRRR_yyyt_id: time=1001.268 calls=94731
```

Advise appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. If it is "dying" can you post the error message? If it is running for a long time you haven't really given us any information to go on.

Comment: @RichardHuxton It just running, running running, It can go for 20 minutes and on, and nothing happens. `Executing...` But when 2 inserts executing separately, in separate transactions, they together execute in about 4 seconds. No Error! Or, at least no error in 20+ minutes

Comment: So. We'll need to know things like current table sizes, number of rows involved in both inserts and ideally EXPLAIN ANALYZE (or since it won't finish EXPLAIN output). Also "Executing..." isn't something that psql would be printing.

Comment: @RichardHuxton table1 has 550,000. table2 is empty. insert 1 - 58K, insert 2 - 94K. I query tables this morning and it had data. Completed overnight? This is something with selecting uncommitted data. For the `executing`. it is saying `waiting for the query to complete..` I use Visual Studio Code PostgreSql extension. When do `begin; insert... select... commit;` it works fast. It selects those uncommitted rows  . can I explain analyze both together?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Think like this.. If the DML #2, executed on committed rows work fast. But not working well on uncommitted rows... what can be the issue. For example, in sql server I can have a temp table, uncommitted, and it is still working.

Comment: Uncommitted isn't relevant here. They are both in the same transaction. I wondered about table statistics, but table1 isn't empty before you start. It could still be that I suppose. Try sticking `ANALYZE table1;` in between the two queries. Maybe the first insert skews the stats for the particular where clause of the second query and the auto-vacuum kicked in when you ran them separately.

Comment: @RichardHuxton added `ANALYZE table1;` and it still hanging there... 5 min or so. At least I learned how to kill the execution. I also ran as 2 highlighted statements without `begin`.. same result

Comment: @RichardHuxton Updated, now with definitive behavior

Answer (score -1):

**Based on the information you have provided, it seems that the issue is that the second query is trying to access data that has not yet been committed by the first query. This is because the two queries are running in the same transaction, and the second query is not waiting for the first query to finish before it starts.**

To fix this issue, you can either:

1. Run the two queries in separate transactions. This will ensure that the second query does not start until the first query has finished.
2. Use the **WITH** clause to create a temporary table from the results of the first query. The second query can then access the data in the temporary table, which will be guaranteed to be committed.

Example:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE somecondition
)
INSERT INTO table2 (f1, f2)
SELECT c.id, a.id
FROM t1 a
INNER JOIN table1 c ON c.someid = a.someid
WHERE somecondition2;
```

This will create a temporary table called t1 from the results of the first query. The second query can then access the data in t1, which will be guaranteed to be committed.

Comment: This is full of very dubious statements. Totally off the mark. It's GPT-generated, right?

Comment: *"the issue is that the second query is trying to access data that has not yet been committed by the first query"* - what is wrong with that? But I need to try a few things

Comment: *"Run the two queries in separate transactions"* - that was the goal of the exercise - to have 1 transaction

Comment: Running the two queries inisde a single transaction should not be the problem here.